# Anonymous proxy authentication

Tags: forms-authentication, reporting-services, redirect

So I was just reading [How to set Anonymous User as a Specific User](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/668/how-to-set-anonymous-user-as-a-specific-user) and I am not sure exactly how to implement and if it will fully cover my situation. I am trying to tunnel users from Salesforce into SharePoint 2013 Reporting Services. The request from Salesforce contains the URL to render the requested report (only a couple are exposed). We're sending the response back so the report renders inside salesforce.
We need security on SSRS, so I wonder how I can execute FormsAuth.SetAuthCookie to a special AD account and then move the request to the RS and back to the client? Do we set the Salesforce httprequest to a Sharepoint webpart app that does this append and redirect? Maybe passes the SSRS as a string param? How can I get the report back to the original caller then? 
The only step missing from the process is correctly authenticating to the Reporting Service - the url call to SSRS is working fine for anyone on an AD connection.